# Objective C and Swift in same Project - -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am new in Swift,
I have my appDelegate file in Objective-C and my current controller is in Swift. The issue is I have a property in my appdelegate as USER_ID to contain login user id and a token property as AUTH_TOKEN.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * USER_ID;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * AUTH_TOKEN;
```

I want these values on my Swift controller. For this I have an instance of current appDelegate like:

```
let APP_DELEGATE_SWIFT = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
```

and now when I print these to value on Swift controller like:

```
print("AuthToken - \(APP_DELEGATE_SWIFT.auth_TOKEN!)")
print("user id - \(APP_DELEGATE_SWIFT.user_ID!)")
```

I am able to get value of auth_TOKEN, but in the case of user_ID, it gives me error like:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000036783'

Comment: `user_ID` seems to be in reality a `NSNumber` object, not a `NSString` one.

Comment: I don't need it to be as NSNumber. It's working fine on the whole project. Is there any other issue here. Thanks for fast reply.

Comment: `[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` That means that somewhere there is a object where `length` is called on it (can be a hidden call, like when you do `[myLabel setText:myString]`, `length` method is called), but since the object is in fact a `NSNumber`, and don't responds to `length`, that's the explanation. From the little you gave us, I strongly suspect that the `length` is for a `NSString` object (maybe a `NSData` object), and I'd guess it's `USER_ID`.

Answer (score 2):

Error indicates you are using a NSString method on a NSNumber. Please, check if your data are strings.